# mod_tile renders OpenStreetMap without some water

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, rendering, mod-tile

My rendered map:

[image: Nigeria without water]

The same view from openstreetmap.org:

[image: Nigeria with water from openstreetmap.org]

What went wrong?

I downloaded europe_latest.osm.pbf and nigeria_latest.osm.pbf and imported these files using `--append`. Now, I'm trying to import it again by merging both .pbf files - will see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

> What went wrong?

Part of your toolchain is likely not handling [OSM multipolygon relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:multipolygon) well, or not at all. Many big waterways, even if they don't have interior rings (think donut shape polyon), still use the multipolygon relation as a means to manage very large geometries.

Unfortunately, even though multipolygon relations fullfill a clear role in OSM, and have been around for a very long time now, there are still tools out there that don't handle them due to the complexity of processing and the developers unwilling to invest the effort.

I personally think that any tool incapable of handling OSM multipolygon relations is of no use nowadays with the amount of MP relations created in the database.

Anyway, you may be missing any donut shaped buildings and other stuff as well, e.g. think of a building with an interior courtyard, so be aware this is likely not an issue related to waterbodies alone, but generic to your import and toolchain.

Comment: I'm using mod_tile. I think it supports OSM multipolygon relations, isn't it? Moreover, I rendered Poland using this tool and everything looks rather fine unless I missed something.

Comment: I noticed that at least part of the water related features you are missing (the ones I checked at least), seem to only contain the "waterway=riverbank" tag, and not the added "natural=water" tag. It may simply be that your personal style only selects "natural=water", and not "waterway=riverbank", hence you are missing these features. Nowadays, most riverbanks are additionally tagged with "natural=water", but there are still features out there that aren't, so to include them, you will need to adjust your rendering style. E.g. see: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/126534060#map=14/4.7759/7.0755